# Change tab title using css command

Tags: html, css

Having in source code this:

```
<head>
<title> My title here </title>
</head>
```

How is it possible to change the text of title using css command?

```
title{
content: "New title!" !important;
}
```

Comment: How important is it that you do it in CSS? You can do this easily in Javascript.

Comment: I would recommend doing this using javascript rather than CSS.

Comment: I really don't get why you can't just do this with Javascript.

Comment: @DanielWilliams I use bateaux theme in wordpress and I can't find from where to change it

Answer (score 2):

You can try this with css

```
title {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

title:after {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "New title";
}
```

But, I would really advise you to use javascript for this.

```
var title = document.querySelector('title');
title.innerText = 'New title';
```